# Create SQL view using min/max of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I have a table that stores a list of Game IDs, the User IDs of users that played that game, and the Score that each user achieved in the game, like below:

```
GameID     UserID     Score
1          Bob        12
1          Sally      14
2          Bob        17
2          Jane       17
3          Sally      16
3          Jane       10
3          Trish      10
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query to create a view of this data that would tell me how many games each user has won, drawn, and lost based on the score. So the view would look like below:

```
UserId     NumWins     NumLosses     NumDraws
Bob        0           1             1
Sally      2           0             0
Jane       0           1             1
Trish      0           1             0
```

I'm trying to come up with the syntax to create a view that transforms the data this way, but am having trouble.

Comment: Check your sample data and expected results again. There are 3 players for gameid = 3. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, a game can have any number of players, so gameid 3 is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RANK()` window function and conditional aggregation:

```
with
  ranks as (
    select *, rank() over (partition by gameid order by score desc) rnk
  from tablename
  ),
  cte as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by gameid, rnk) counter
    from ranks
  )
select userid,
  sum(case when rnk = 1 and counter = 1 then 1 else 0 end) NumWins,          
  sum(case when rnk > 1 then 1 else 0 end) NumLosses,
  sum(case when rnk = 1 and counter > 1 then 1 else 0 end) NumDraws
from cte  
group by userid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c040b9c73508a02d47367cc99b654635).
Results:

```
> userid | NumWins | NumLosses | NumDraws
> :----- | ------: | --------: | -------:
> Bob    |       0 |         1 |        1
> Jane   |       0 |         1 |        1
> Sally  |       2 |         0 |        0
> Trish  |       0 |         1 |        0
```

Comment: Brilliant, this looks to be doing what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional aggregation as the following

```
SELECT * INTO Games
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 'Bob',     12),
  (1, 'Sally',     14),
  (2, 'Bob',     17),
  (2, 'Jane',     17),
  (3, 'Sally',     16),
  (3, 'Jane',     10),
  (3, 'Trish',     10)
) T(GameId, UserId, Score);

SELECT G.UserId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MXS = Score AND MNS <> Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Wins,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MXS > Score AND Score = MNS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Loses,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MXS = MNS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Draws
FROM Games G
JOIN 
(
  SELECT GameId, MAX(Score) MXS, MIN(Score) MNS
  FROM Games
  GROUP BY GameId
) T(GameId, MXS, MNS) 
ON G.GameId = T.GameId
GROUP BY UserId
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a06c61c01664d7613921a089dda0c469)

Comment: There's a flaw in the logic at "case when MXS=MNS then Draw". If I have a three-player game and two players score 10 and one player scores 9, then MXS != MNS, but it is still a draw.

Comment: @MAR Let's assume `(3, 'Sally',     9)` the results will be 1 wins, 1 loses, 0 draws for Sally which is true.

Comment: Sally's stats would be correct in that case, but Trish and Jane's would be wrong. The outcome of GameId 3 should be Sally loses, but Trish and Jane draw (since they both have 10 and Sally has 9). But your query would show Trish and Jane both winning that game.